# illegalArgument exception while trying to unregister broadcast receiver

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments

I am unregistering a broadcast receiver inside onDestroy ( ) method. Even though I am checking null values.

My code is like

```
 If (broadcastReceiver!=null)
    {
       activity.unregisterReceiver    (broadcastReceiver);
    }
```

What is the issue?.

Comment: What did you declare `broadcastReceiver` as?

Comment: May be your receiver is already unregistered. Or has never been registered with `registerReceiver()`

Comment: I have registered it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can maintain a boolean check for registering and unrestering a broadcast receiver.

I am giving some sample code here. It may help you.

Initially

```
ReceiverRegistered = false;


 public void registerReceiverFunction() 
        {
            ReceiverRegistered = true;

            BR = new BroadcastReceiver() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) 
                        {
                              activity.unregisterReceiver(BR);
                              ReceiverRegistered = false; 
                        }
                   IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter("updateData");
                   activity.registerReceiver(BR, mFilter);
                }
```

When you required that receiver you can call this function to have a receiver.
If you are trying to un-register the receiver just do

```
           if (ReceiverRegistered) 
                {
                    if(BR!=null)
                      {
                        activity.unregisterReceiver(BR);
                        ReceiverRegistered = false;
                      }
                }
```